# Is php htmlspecialchars safety for JS?

Tags: php, xss, htmlspecialchars

Is php htmlspecialchars safety for JS?

```
var jsVar = "<?php echo(str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n","\r"), "\\n",htmlspecialchars($_GET['p'], ENT_QUOTES))); ?>";
```

How about for multi byte chars?

Comment: Uhhh, it's for **html**. It's in the function name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. For that you'd use `json_encode` (JSON = Javascript notation).

```
var foo = <?php echo json_encode('Foo "Bar" Baz'); ?>;
```

`htmlspecialchars` escapes characters that have a special meaning in HTML. Javascript literals have other special characters you need to take care of, so HTML escaping doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yeah I think so. But my boss said "this is completely safety! isn't it?" I can't complain for him..

Comment: @freddie Well, it may even be true, if quotes are escaped and you're always enclosing your values in quotes (in JS). It's the wrong tool for the job though, and you're probably messing up your values more than you need to.

Comment: I think this confusion may came up from escaping the whole HTML, including JS literals, and because JavaScript is only executed by special HTML syntax (usually tag or attribute) and you escape that HTML syntax, so it no longer gives the instruction => JS will not get executed :)